# Can I have two connector tags for the same address in server.xml of tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, keystore

I have got two DNS entries for the same IP address. And I have two ssl  keystores for each one of them.
Can I mention both the keystores in server.xml as shown below ?

```
<Connector address="my_IP_Addres" port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                         maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                           enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                           keystoreFile="1st_keystore_file" keystorePass="1st_key_pass"
                           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" />

<Connector address="my_IP_Addres" port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                         maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                           enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                           keystoreFile="2nd_keystore_file" keystorePass="2nd_key_pass"
                           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" />
```

Comment: no. but you can merge content of these keystores within keytool.

Comment: How can we merge two keystores ? Each keystore will be having a unique private key

Comment: I mean you can create connectors for two different IP:port endpoints, but manage key/cert pairs within a single keystore file. See keyAlias parameter in SSL Support section of [tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use several connectors to single endpoint with Tomcat. HTTPS is HTTP over SSL. It means

1. client and server establish SSL connection, using only IP:port pairs during handshake procedure
2. client and server exchange HTTP messages over established SSL connection

DNS entries (host->IP) in your case allows client to resolve server IP **before** SSL handshake. But during handshake hostnames are not used. This is why server cannot resolve which key/cert pair to use on this phase. And this is the cause, why the only key/cert pair can be provided.

See [HTTPS limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Limitations) for more details.